# How to get two AI civilizations to go to war against each other?

Tags: civilization-5

I saw a video that suggested a good tactic is to get two opposing AI civs to go to war with each other, and then to pick off the weaker one near the end of the war.

My question is: How *exactly* do I get two AI civs to fight each other or is it even possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can bribe the AI to go to war against other AIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in the diplomatic/trade interface with other leaders, one of the options you can expand is "Other Players" - and in this submenu, there are options for asking for a declaration of war on another civilization.

Bear in mind that this is one of the more costly things you can ask for of an AI Civ, and they'll often refuse ("There is no way to make this deal work") or ask for exorbitant fees.

Comment: exorbitant fees. Aka. BRIBE. :P